# Convert MS Access dynamic column in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

I would like to convert this example of MS Access dynamic query in T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    iif(expression='A', value, 0) as vA,
    iif(expression='B', value, 0) as vB,
    vA-vB as diff
FROM 
    MyTable
```

I tried this code, but the compiler throw me that the new dynamic columns vA and vB in the expression `vA-vB as diff` are not recognized.

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    CASE WHEN expression = 'A' then value else 0 end AS vA,
    CASE WHEN expression = 'B' then value else 0 end AS vB,
    vA-vB as diff
FROM 
    MyTable
```

Comment: your aliases are defined when the row finishes processing. therefore they're not available in a "read" context elsewhere in the same row.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the alias name which is defined in same select statement. Try this.

```
SELECT NAME,
       CASE WHEN expression = 'A' THEN value ELSE 0 END               AS vA,
       CASE WHEN expression = 'B' THEN value ELSE 0 END               AS vB,
       ( CASE WHEN expression = 'A' THEN value ELSE 0 END ) - 
       ( CASE WHEN expression = 'B' THEN value ELSE 0 END ) AS diff
FROM   MyTable
```

or Make the query as `Sub select` and find the `diff` in `outer query`

```
SELECT vA,
       VB,
       vA - vB AS Diff
FROM   (SELECT NAME,
               CASE WHEN expression = 'A' THEN value ELSE 0 END AS vA,
               CASE WHEN expression = 'B' THEN value ELSE 0 END AS vB
        FROM   MyTable) A
```

Comment: It's one of the many idiosyncrasies of Access that you can use aliases in a `SELECT` clause - although as far as I remember, they have to be defined in sequence. It can be useful, but it can be a total nightmare if there's a calculated field in a query with the same name as a table field.